# 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'',

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a function that uses router and the subscribe function but when I create the spyon an error appears, how can I fix it?

This is the error:

'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'', '; Zone:', 'ProxyZone', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'

My function:

```
goto = (...params) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.router.navigate(params);
            this.router.events.subscribe(ev => {
                if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                    this.menu.clickReload.emit(params.join('/'));
                }
            })
        }, 300)
    }
```

My test:

```
describe('goto()', () => {
        it('should navigate to the correct url', () => {
            let params = '/test';
            let spy1 = spyOn(component.router, 'navigate').and.callThrough();
            let spy2 = spyOn(component.router.events, 'subscribe').and.callThrough();

            component.goto(params);

            expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(spy2).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```